# Sending XFile image to API using MultipartFile - Flutter

Tags: android, react-native, flutter, dart, multipartform-data

I have an application that caters for web, android and ios.
I have implemented the packages below

https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker/example

- image_picker: ^0.8.2
- image_picker_for_web: ^2.1.1

---

Tasks:

1. User needs to select multiple images (When debugging thru android, i sometimes receive websocket connection expection, and application exits without any error message. Bonus if youre able to provide some insights to this issue as well)
2. Clicks submit to upload the images (XFile) to API

```
class UserAttachments {
  List<XFile>? attachments = [];
  int userID = 0;
}

Future<String> submitImage(UserAttachments ua) async {
  http.MultipartRequest request =
      new http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(kAttachmentsURI));

  Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"};

  ua.attachments!.forEach((element) async {
    var bytes = element.readAsBytes();
    request.files.add(new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file', await bytes));
  });

  request.headers.addAll(headers);
  request.fields['userID'] = '23';

  http.StreamedResponse responseAttachmentSTR = await request.send();

  print(responseAttachmentSTR.statusCode);
  return "SENT"; // + "  - Respomse:  " + map.toString();
}
```

Above code doesn't seem to work. Any solutions that cater for web/android/ios?

Comment: Hi, you need to be more specific in your question. What is the exact problem here?

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to pass the file to the api, returns me generic error 500.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use async on forEach, because that will just return an array of promises and won't wait for them. To fix this, you can use a `for loop` for asynchronous functions.

```
for(var i = 0; i < ua.attachments!.length; i++) {
  var element = ua.attachments[i];
  var bytes = element.readAsBytes();
  request.files.add(new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file', await bytes));
}
```

And you can optimize this code using `Future.wait`

```
Future<String> submitImage(UserAttachments ua) async {
      http.MultipartRequest request =
          new http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(kAttachmentsURI));
    
      Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"};
    
      var bytes = await Future.wait(ua.attachments!.map((el) => el.readAsBytes()));
      request.files.addAll(bytes.map((b) => new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('file', b)));
    
      request.headers.addAll(headers);
      request.fields['userID'] = '23';
    
      http.StreamedResponse responseAttachmentSTR = await request.send();
    
      print(responseAttachmentSTR.statusCode);
      return "SENT";
}
```

Comment: Received 500 from API
I checked the url path for image - http://localhost:59934/47aab53a-2889-4d65-9793-216693a248b8
might this cause the issue?